# Hypotenuse program, can't figure out how to let program run until user enters 2

Tags: java

I am writing a program that finds the hypotenuse of a triangle, I need to let the program run an arbitrary amount of times until the user enters 2. I cannot figure out how to end the program when the user enters 2.

```
package assignment5a;

import java.util.Scanner;//import Scanner 

public class Assignment5A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//new Scanner variable
        int answer;
        double side1, side2, result;


        System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle or enter 2 to quit.");
        answer = sc.nextInt();

        while(answer < 0 || answer > 2){

            System.err.println("Please enter a valid answer.");

            System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle or enter 2 to quit.");
            answer = sc.nextInt();


        }

        System.out.println("Enter side 1 of the triangle :");//input for side 1
        side1 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter side 2 of the triangle :");//input for side 2
        side2 = sc.nextDouble();

        result = hypotenuse(side1, side2);//declares result as the result of the method hypotenuse

        System.out.printf("Hypotenuse of your triangle is: %.2f%n", result);//prints results




    }

    public static double hypotenuse(double s1, double s2){//method for calculating hypotenuse

        double hypot;

        hypot = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(s1, 2) + Math.pow(s2, 2)));
        return hypot;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (answer == 2) return;`

Comment: Where in your code do you think the decision to exit would best be made?

Comment: I need it to loop the main method pretty much, it needs to prompt the user for the sides of the triangle after they enter 1, so it would not exit until they enter 2.

Answer (score 1):

Wilmol's answer and Elliot Frisch's answer / comment are half the solution.

The other half is that you need an outer loop around most of the logic so it'll repeat.  Put most of `main()` inside a loop that uses `while (true) {` to start so that it'll loop forever.

Then use the logic of `if (answer == 2) {` ... to actually break out when the user inputs 2.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn’t run right.. I’m not sure if I didn’t do it right or not.

Comment: @JoshAckerman Why not post the code for what you tried? As it stands there is no attempt in your current code to repeat your logic, nor exit on a '2'. No one will be able to provide a helpful answer unless they can understand what you are struggling with. This answer explains exactly what you need to do to achieve your  described desired outcome - what aspect of it is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

```
if (answer == 2)
{
break;
}

if (answer == 2)
{
return;
}

if (answer == 2)
{
System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Your answers helped a lot but i ended up putting two while loops. The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//new Scanner variable
    int answer;
    double side1, side2, result;


    System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle or enter 2 to quit.");
    answer = sc.nextInt();

    while(answer < 0 || answer > 2){

        System.err.println("Please enter a valid answer.");

        System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle or enter 2 to quit.");
        answer = sc.nextInt();
    }  
        while(answer == 1){

    System.out.println("Enter side 1 of the triangle :");//input for side 1
    side1 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter side 2 of the triangle :");//input for side 2
    side2 = sc.nextDouble();

    result = hypotenuse(side1, side2);//declares result as the result of the method hypotenuse

    System.out.printf("Hypotenuse of your triangle is: %.2f%n", result);//prints results

    System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle or enter 2 to quit.");
    answer = sc.nextInt();
 }
```

}
    public static double hypotenuse(double s1, double s2){//method for calculating hypotenuse

```
    double hypot;

    hypot = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(s1, 2) + Math.pow(s2, 2)));
    return hypot;
}
```

}